# Strange behaving Routes with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've fought with, in my case, totally quaint behaving of routes.rb. I've tried to implement Carmen gem into my rails app. I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/jim/carmen-demo-app). I wanted just two dependent select boxes where first one is Country and the second one is Region(in this case - subregion). I spent almost two hours finding out, why it isn't working. Finally, the solution was quite simple - just switch two lines in routes.rb. And now my question. Can me please anyone explain why, in first case, was the response from server error and why my rails app tried to send the request on show action? I really don't get it. Thank you.

**Errors:**

**`Routes.rb`**

```
resources :orders
get '/orders/subregion_options' => 'orders#subregion_options'
```

**`Server output`**

```
Started GET "/orders/subregion_options?parent_region=US" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-13 23:18:35 -0700
Processing by OrdersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"parent_region"=>"US", "id"=>"subregion_options"}
  Order Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "subregion_options"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order with id=subregion_options):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:26:in `show'
```

**Correct behavior:**

**`Routes.rb`**

```
get '/orders/subregion_options' => 'orders#subregion_options'
resources :orders
```

**`Server output`**

```
Started GET "/orders/subregion_options?parent_region=US" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-13 23:20:10 -0700
Processing by OrdersController#subregion_options as HTML
  Parameters: {"parent_region"=>"US"}
  Rendered orders/_subregion_select.html.erb (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the routes in `routes.rb` are defined in the order they appear. When you write `resources :orders`, you are implicitly creating a route that matches `GET /orders/:id` to the `show` action on your `orders` controller, so when you go to `/orders/subregion_options` rails interprets `subregion_options` as the `id`, hence the error.

In your second version, you change the order and thus `/orders/subregion_options` gets correctly matched to the `subregion_options` action *before* the resource route is defined. That's why the second version works and the first doesn't.

Incidentally, this is a cleaner way to define that route:

```
resources :orders do
  collection do
    get 'subregion_options'
  end
end
```